# wx SplashScreen doesn't work

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I've used the sample code from the wiki but it just doesn't work for me, I see nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
import wx

app = wx.App()

aBitmap = wx.Image(name = "wxPyWiki.jpg").ConvertToBitmap()
splashStyle = wx.SPLASH_CENTRE_ON_SCREEN | wx.SPLASH_TIMEOUT
splashDuration = 1000

splash = wx.adv.SplashScreen(aBitmap, splashStyle,
                                 splashDuration, None)
splash.Show()
wx.Yield()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note SplashScreen is not in wx.adv in wxpython 2.8.12 (and I am using it)

This works (with my own image)

```
import wx

app = wx.App()
aBitmap = wx.Image(name = "zimages/gato.jpg").ConvertToBitmap()
splashStyle = wx.SPLASH_CENTRE_ON_SCREEN | wx.SPLASH_TIMEOUT
splashDuration = 1000

splash = wx.SplashScreen(aBitmap, splashStyle,
                                 splashDuration, None)
splash.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

The only difference is the use of `wx.Yield` vs `app.MainLoop`.
I am not sure about the purpose of `Yield` in wxpython 2.9 but note anyway that [`wx.Yield()` has been deprecated](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/functions.html?highlight=yield#Yield)

Comment: Yes, it was in wx for me too.

Comment: @AwarwwagRewafgggs Check the wxpython docs and demos package you can download from wxpython website. You will find examples there